# TWRP patching /system

Tags: rooting, recovery-mode, twrp

I recently flashed a stock system image to take an OTA update and have only *booted* to TWRP since. (I didn't flash it) I did root, though. 
When I was browsing /system I found that reboot-from-recovery.p was renamed to reboot-from-recovery.bak 
My question is was this done by SuperSU or TWRP? and could this be the only modification?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's done by TWRP.

If you're rooted, SuperSU modifies /system as well to put files there to give you root.

Comment: Is that the only change? Can I reverse it by, say, flashing "undo-perm-recovery-signed"?

Comment: Yeah you could, but the reason TWRP renames that is so that when you want to boot to recovery, you'll boot to TWRP and not stock Android recovery.

Comment: Many Thanks. But it seems like a pointless thing to happen when TWRP is not even flashed.